# CUDA 8 compile errors with -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, cuda

I am trying to convert some code to use CUDA, and I think I am having compatibility issues. We use CMake. These are the gcc and CUDA versions that I use:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

In the CMakeLists.txt file, this is set:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/stddef.h(436): error: identifier "nullptr" is undefined

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include/stddef.h(436): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5/bits/c++config.h(200): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/5/exception(63): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/5/exception(68): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/5/exception(76): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/5/exception(83): error: expected a ";"

/usr/include/c++/5/exception(93): error: expected a "{"
...
```

I found [this discussion](https://github.com/torch/cutorch/issues/413), which says to change the C++ flag to `-std=c++98` , however this won't do for the project as it makes extensive use of C++11 code. Is there a solution for this? It doesn't appear to be an unique problem, but I can't seem to find a solution...

This is the output when I run `cmake`, so I know it is indeed using gcc 5.4 and not another version.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found version "8.0") 
-- Found OpenCV: /usr/local (found version "3.2.0") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found version "2.7.12") 
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Configuring done
-- Generating
```

Comment: use `std=c++11`? I fail to see what this has to do with CUDA

Comment: Thanks @talonmies, I think that solved it... you are right it's probably not CUDA's problem, but it's what I am trying to add, so jumped to the conclusion I am having issues with CUDA. Wouldn't have known to search for/use std=c++11 without your suggestion.

Comment: Would you mind adding your solution as an answer?

Comment: @talonmies done, thank you.

Comment: Also, in a multi compiler environment /usr/bin/cc may not point to the gcc version you are supposed to work with. Just launch `readlink -e /usr/bin/cc` to be 100% sure it points to your desired gcc version. `$(readlink -e /usr/bin/cc) --version` does it oneliner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to require a more recent version of CMake, the more portable solution is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.3)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)  # not necessary, but encouraged
```

I'm about 90% sure it came in with [`v3.1.3`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html).  Make sure you set this **before** you create any specific targets (e.g., `cuda_add_library` or `cuda_add_executable`).

Note also that if you are using traditional `find_package(CUDA)` and `cuda_add_library` etc, you will probably also want

```
set(CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS ON)
```

Otherwise `nvcc` does not by default inherit these definitions.

Answer (score 1):

A simple change from

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
```

To

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Solved my problem. Thanks talonmies for the solution.